# How to save Graphics created on a picture box?

Tags: c#, graphics

I am creating a graphics object using `pictureBox.CreateGraphics()` method. I am using the picture box to load an image and edit it by drawing on it. I want to save the "new" image (the edited one) to a new file.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Use Graphics.FromImage() instead of CreateGraphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [hard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save.aspx). But the tricky part is how do you do "drawing on it".

Comment: `code` Graphics g = PBBlueprint.CreateGraphics(); //PBblueprint is the picturebox element
g.DrawLine(pen, Point1, Point2);